# ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref - no error when running python script.py, error when running script.py from bash shell script

Tags: python, bash, import, weak-references

I am trying to import a package that requires sklearn. This is in a test script named script.py. When I run: `python script.py allele_1`, I do not get an error. However, when I include this command inside a bash shell script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
allele=($(ls $1 | grep H))
python script.py $allele
```

I get the following error

```
File "/home/jhuang/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/mhcnuggets/src/dataset.py", line 12, in <mod                                                                                              
ule>
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
File "/home/jhuang/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
  import logging
File "/home/jhuang/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in 
<module>
import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
File "/home/jhuang/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

I've seen similar questions, but have not seen a definitive answer, nor have I seen any question in the context of command line vs shell script execution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a problem mixing Python 3 and Python 2 stdlibs, e.g., by putting the Python 3 lib in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable but then running Python 2.7.

Comment: How can I check this? I tried `import sys` `print(sys.path)`, but this path only contained python2.7 locations

Comment: First, are you sure the `python` being run in your bash script is the same as the `python` you run on the command line? If you `print sys.executable` in both places, do you get the same answer? Next, check that `sys.path` is the same in both places.

Comment: I tried both - it seems like they're both the same

Answer (score 2):

This issue is probably you have installed python2 with homebrew which is conflicting with system python version. Try uninstalling python@2 homebrew version and you should be good to go.

```
brew remove python@2 --ignore-dependencies
```